# realpath (GNU coreutils 8.22) does resolve "." symlink regardless of "-s"

Tags: unix, shell, path, symbolic-link, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to use [realpath](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/realpath-invocation.html) in a script which has to ensure that it is located under a certain (possibly symlinked) path. Also the script has to be runnable from any location, so it cannot presume that current directory is the one containing the the script. But...

```
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/script
$ ln -s dir symlink
$ realpath -s symlink/script
/tmp/symlink/script
$ realpath -s symlink       
/tmp/symlink
```

Everything's good for now: `realpath` would resolve symlink by default, but `-s` switch did just what we needed.

```
$ cd symlink 
$ realpath -s script 
/tmp/dir/script
$ realpath -s .
/tmp/dir
```

Why result is the same as without `-s` in this case? Even if one supposes that symlink resolving works in a special way for current directory, here is inconsistency anyway:

```
$ realpath -s ../symlink/script 
/tmp/symlink/script
```

Answer (score 0):

The man page of `realpath` says:

> ```
> realpath -s filename
> ```
>
> When the -s option is used realpath only removes the . and .. directories, but not symbolic links from filename. If the given filename argument is relative (i.e. does not start with '/'), realpath -s prepends to it the current directory name as obtained from the getcwd(2) system call before further processing.

As you call `realpath -s script` and `script` is no symlink, realpath prepends just the current working dir as given by `pwd`.

*However, it seems, that the behavior of realpath depends of its resp. the getcwd() implementation; under cygwin `realpath -s script` shows an absolute path.*

You can get an absolute path, e.g. with

```
realpath -s $(pwd -P)/script
```

as `pwd -P` print the full filename of the current working directory, avoiding all symlinks.

Or use

```
readlink -e script
```

where `-e` is for "canonicalizing by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively".